# How to forward a domain without an absolute link

Tags: domains, dns, server, domain-forwarding

We have multiple sites within our server:

We mostly use a www.example.com/businessid=21 type URI format.

Unfortunately, we've changed the DNS for domain www.example.com to another server.

One of our clients will not change their DNS and will only use forwarding on their domain.

Is there a way to we can still point to the /businessid=21 site? given that we no longer have the www.example.com part of the url (i.e. just using the ip address of the server?)

Comment: It doesn't make sense to me I'm afraid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does a direct link to the ip work? If the ip link goes to the root of your server, then you could do something like: `127.0.0.1/~username/example.com/`. But, that might not actually work at all, depending how the server is set up.

I'd contact your host for help with this one.